# Enable all the themes during installation of module drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

How can i update a table during the installation of a module in drupal 7? i used the following code . But it is not working

```
function mymodule_install() {
drupal_install_schema('template_config');
db_update('system')
 ->fields(array(   
'status' => 1,
))
->condtion('type','theme','=')
->execute();
}
```

What is wrong in this code. i want to enable all the themes on the time of installation of mymodule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call `drupal_install_schema()` from a `hook_install()` in Drupal 7, the schema will automatically be installed when the module is. Other than that your code will definitely work but I think you'll need to clear the caches straight after. Your install function should probably look like this:

```
function mymodule_install() {
  db_update('system')
    ->fields(array('status' => 1))
    ->condtion('type','theme','=')
    ->execute();

  cache_clear_all();
}
```

Also make sure you're actually uninstalling and reinstalling your module, not just disabling it and then re-enabling it (click the 'Uninstall' tab from the modules page when you've disabled the module).

Comment: i tried this code and uninstalled  and reinstalled the module. But the change is not affecting.

Comment: Try `db_query("UPDATE {system} SET status = 1 WHERE type = 'theme'");`...that will absolutely have to work. Try adding `drupal_set_message('test');` in your install function to make sure the hook is being called, and then check the database table once you've done the reinstall. If it hasn't updated the `status` column, there's something  wrong with your installation of Drupal

Comment: while i print just a hii im drupal_install() it gives hii and an error message  "Fatal error: Call to undefined method UpdateQuery::condtion() in momodule.install" . but db_query("UPDATE {system} SET status = 1 WHERE type = 'theme'"); this works fine for me

Comment: Ahhh you mis-spelled `condition`!!